# Tooltip on a column of cells in JSP, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, tooltip, cell

I Want to show tool tip on a column of cells which is being displayed on JSP using HTML and Bean Write tags.

I have tried using "Title" attribute to show the tool tip, but it doesn't display.

I have also tried using onMouseOver, onmouseover, onMouseover attributes, whereby I was trying to call a function in Javascript, which may display the tool tip.

But, the problem is, forgetting tool tip dispaly logic, it doesnot even display a single alert statement written inside the function being called on event. But actually, it stops displaying the entire data of the table, might be JSP Compilation issue.

The display logic of table is pasted below.

Table  -

```
var one_rte_HTML = 
            '<td><table width="890" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-top:solid 1px black;">'+
            '   <tr class="<bean:write name="couleurListe"/>" height="25" style="font-size:10pt">'+
            '       <td align="center" width="155"><bean:write name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.d_date"/></td>'+
            '       <td align="center" width="70"><bean:write name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.v_typeRTE" /></td>'+
            '       <td align="center" width="70"><bean:write name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.v_priorite"/></td>'+
            '       <td width="1" style="border-left:solid 1px black"><div style="width:1px"></div></td>'+
            '   </tr>'+
            '</table></td>';
            rt_index = add_node(foldersTree,'',one_rte_HTML);

function add_node(parentfolderObject, itemLabel, string_HTML) {
var newObj;

newObj = insFld(parentfolderObject, gFld(itemLabel, "javascript:parent.op()"))
newObj.prependHTML = string_HTML
return newObj
}
```

functions -

```
function insFld(parentFolder, childFolder) 
{ return parentFolder.addChild(childFolder) }


function gFld(description, hreference) 
{ folder = new Folder(description, hreference);  return folder; }

function addChild(childNode) 
{   this.children[this.nChildren] = childNode ;
    childNode.parentObj = this
    this.nChildren++ 
    return childNode 
}
```

Here, I need to display a tool tip for the `<td>` having property="rte.v_typeRTE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer of the question.. :)
The things were not so big which I had thought of.. it got solved with a simple DIV tag usage..

Adding to the original question, My requirement was around dynamic tool tip.. i.e. if the property returns "CREPAR" I need to show X tool tip and if property returns "CIDPAR" I need to show Y tool tip..!

Here is my new code.. You will see few 
    logic:equal
and 
    div
tags added to it...

```
var one_rte_HTML = 
        '<td><table width="890" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-top:solid 1px black;">'+
        '   <tr class="<bean:write name="couleurListe"/>" height="25" style="font-size:10pt">'+
        '       <td align="center" width="155"><bean:write name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.d_date"/></td>'+
        '       <logic:equal name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.v_typeRTE" value="CREPAR">'+
        '       <td align="center" width="70"><div title="Création d’un PAR"><bean:write name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.v_typeRTE"/></div></td></logic:equal>'+
        '       <logic:equal name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.v_typeRTE" value="CIDPAR">'+
        '       <td align="center" width="70"><div title="Changement d’identifiant d’un PAR"><bean:write name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.v_typeRTE"/></div></td></logic:equal>'+
        '       <td align="center" width="70"><bean:write name="elementSelectionnableRTE" property="rte.v_priorite"/></td>'+
        '       <td width="1" style="border-left:solid 1px black"><div style="width:1px"></div></td>'+
        '   </tr>'+
        '</table></td>';
        rt_index = add_node(foldersTree,'',one_rte_HTML);
```

Thanks stackoverflow!!

Comment: @BalusC - Agreed, it's not a JSP problem, but the reason I had told so was because I had used the code inside JSP. I had thought like it could be solved by using some CSS and JS inside JSP. Thanks for making it more accurate!! :)